# Python config - loop through section and create variables

Tags: python, config, configparser

I have various variables I am setting in a bunch of Python files and I want to move them to a config file. While the python config parser library allows me to centralise these variables, it still requires a lot of code in each file to fetch every config setting and assign to a variable.

What I would like to do is minimise the code used to set these variables. So for the below settings.ini I would like to be able to just use something like `setVars('QUEUE')` to loop through the section named QUEUE and set variables in the current file with the same name as their key in the settings.ini file. I have tried a few approaches but without success. Is this even possible?

```
[QUEUE]
queueSrvr = '192.168.0.50'
queuePort = 5672
queueUser = 'guest'
queuePass = 'guest'

[DATABASE]
dbase  = 'robotAI'
user   = 'root'
passwd = 'Password123'
servr  = 'localhost'
```

Below is one example that IMHO should work.

```
import configparser

def setVariables(section):
    global x
    x = "just a test"
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read('/home/lee/Downloads/robotAI4/settings.ini')
    data = dict(config.items(section))
    for key in data:
        print('global ' + key)
        exec('global ' + key)
        print(key + ' = ' + data[key])
        exec(key + ' = ' + data[key])
        
setVariables('QUEUE')   

print (x)
print (queueuser)
```

But what I get from this is the following output:

```
global queuesrvr
queuesrvr = '192.168.0.50'
global queueport
queueport = 5672
global queueuser
queueuser = 'guest'
global queuepass
queuepass = 'guest'
just a test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Downloads/robotAI4/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (queueuser)
NameError: name 'queueuser' is not defined
```

It is quite clearly looping through the values and running the global statements and then setting the values. So why does x have a value outside the function but not queueuser?

Comment: It won't. Don't dynamically create variables, in general it's not possible (it is possible in the global scope, but it's really not advisable). Just use your `config` object, or write it out the variables you want by hand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you know why the code I have there returns a key error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, if I put your example in a file and load it like you do, `config['QUEUE']` doesn't throw an error.

Comment: rookie error. just realised I need the full path to the settings.ini the way I was running the main file. so I can now get the code to work, but as you say - it doesnt set the variables. There must be a way to do this.

Comment: You _can_ do this as per the dupe, but please don't. And execing user input is inherently insecure.

Comment: Consider [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/5067311) if someone can meddle with your config file.

Comment: If someone can meddle with the config file, then they have the keys to the kingdom anyway. But I will take the advice. I found a way to structure things so it didnt make too much extra code anyway. Thanks all.